# "Кусочек асфальта под колёсами был единственной уликой времени"?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Ныне эта обитель – епископская резиденция. Она встретила нас
>   невообразимой чистотой и порядком. Такой ухоженной территории я не
>   видела давно. Всё вокруг просто сияло! Паркинг располагался под
>   высокой скалой с острой вершиной, что поддерживала небо над мощными
>   стенами грубой кладки, а **кусочек асфальта под колёсами был
>   единственной уликой времени**.

Можно ли говорить об улике времени, не говоря какого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уличают кого-то *в чём-то*, **улика** бывает *против* кого-то, а если *улика кого-то* (здесь *всё равно какого* времени), то этот кто-то её нашёл (припас) в результате расследования. Поэтому здесь выходит смысл "время *имеет* улику (против кого-то, чего-то)" - странно. Нужно что-то вроде **следа**, **приметы**, **отметины**. Может подойти *единственное **напоминание** о новых временах*.

Comment: Саш, допустим, автор сменит улику на *след, примету, отметину*... а ЧЕГО надоть?

Comment: Здесь со временем без прилагательного  тоже проблема: по контесту это "наше время" - раз асфальт епископу противопоставлен. Без епископа можно было бы подумать, что прошло много времени и асфальт успел разрушиться. Можно попытаться **примета современности**, **наших дней**.

Answer (score 1):

***...а кусочек асфальта под колёсами был единственной уликой нового времени.***

УЛИКА, -и; ж. Предмет или обстоятельство, уличающее кого-л. в чём-л., свидетельствующее о чьей-л. виновности.

**Переносное значение** в словаре не обозначено, но оно вполне может быть авторским, кроме того, можно найти тексты, где использовано именно **переносное значение слова.**

Подбор слов – **это тоже стиль автора**, его определенное настроение и отношение, не стоит так легко менять их.

Пример:

Но теперь, очевидно, предания кончились; « Обломов» может служить для будущего историка русской литературы **только уликой того**, как непрочны бывают всякие начинания и как легко они сводятся на нет. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Уличная философия (1868-1883)]